# Binding between Label and HashMap not updating

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, binding

Consider the following use case:
A simple GUI with four Labels that should be bound to a HashMap.get("key") in order to give a basic multi language implementation. Other languages are stored in similar HashMaps and will overwrite the bound map as needed.

So on button press the GUI language should change from german to english, or italian ect. Translations are done and don't need to be fetched from google.

The HashMaps are ObservableMaps.
The labels are created in FXML and their FX:id is lab1, lab2, lab3 and lab4.

```
private ObservableMap<String, StringProperty>   listHash    = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
private ObservableMap<String, StringProperty>   listHashDeu = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

listHash.put("lab1", new SimpleStringProperty("Label one"));
listHash.put("lab2", new SimpleStringProperty("Label two"));
listHash.put("lab3", new SimpleStringProperty("Label three"));
listHash.put("lab4", new SimpleStringProperty("Label four"));
listHashDeu.put("lab1", new SimpleStringProperty("Label eins"));
listHashDeu.put("lab2", new SimpleStringProperty("Label zwei"));
listHashDeu.put("lab3", new SimpleStringProperty("Label drei"));
listHashDeu.put("lab4", new SimpleStringProperty("Label vier"));
```

Binding is done like this:

```
lab1.textProperty().bind(listHash.get("lab1"));
lab2.textProperty().bind(listHash.get("lab2"));
lab3.textProperty().bind(listHash.get("lab3"));
lab4.textProperty().bind(listHash.get("lab4"));
```

Changing of languages is done like this:

```
listHash.putAll(listHashDeu);
```

Adding a change listener to listHash shows that change is indeed being registered. System.out.println shows all values are indeed updated as well. Yet the labels remain unchanged.

I have tried using differend lists like HashMaps, Maps wrapped in an ObservableMap and List StringProperty.
The only luck i had was with List StringProperty, tho indirectly and seemingly dirty.

Using List StringProperty, then binding index 0 to the Label and storing the languages in index 1-x, then overwriting index 0 with whatever language i need indeed does update the labels. But this approach seems pretty bad and hard to maintain. Adding new languages would need all lists to be updated AND i would need to have a list for every GUI element in my application.

So, what am i missing to get the desired result with a HashMap or similarly well suited form of storing several dozen GUI element translations?

Comment: You are not changing the value of the `StringProperty` to which the labels are bound: you are replacing the `StringProperty` in the map with a different `StringProperty`. (The label is still bound to the previous `StringProperty`.)

Comment: for (Entry<String, StringProperty> p : listHashDeu.entrySet())
    {
  listHash.get(p.getKey()).setValue(p.getValue().get());
    } Works. But i will have to find out why exactly. .put is listed and explained as overwriting the value only, in about every topic i could find. Thanks man.

Comment: That should work, but it's kind of ugly. Why not use one of the methods in the linked question?

Comment: I just tried it and had no luck. Labels will not update if i use .put or .putAll, only if i use .setValue sadly. It may be ugly, but definitly less ugly then using a list of stringproperties for every UI element.

Comment: I updated the linked question/answer with a complete working example.

Comment: Works if i change the map from string, stringproperty to string string. Nice, thank you!